# javac powershell classpath separator

Tags: powershell, classpath, javac, separator

So I'm aware that different operating systems require different classpath separators. I'm running a build of windows where CMD has been replaced with Powershell which is causing problems when using the semi-colon separator.

The command I'm trying to run begins with `cmd /c` to try and get it to run in command prompt instead but I think when PowerShell is parsing the whole command it sees the semi-colon and thinks that is the end!

My whole command is:

`cmd /c javac -cp PATH1;PATH2 -d DESTINATION_PATH SOURCE_PATH`

I have tried using a space, colon and period to no avail. Can anybody suggest a solution?

This is my first question on stackoverflow, hope the community can help and that it will eventually help others. :)

Comment: `-cp "PATH1;PATH2"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you start the process in the following way using Powershell

```
Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c javac -cp PATH1;PATH2 -d DESTINATION_PATH SOURCE_PATH" -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: What do you mean by "CMD has been replaced" ?
CMD is available in all Microsoft operating systems, including but not limited to the latest "Windows 10".

Comment: The machine it does not work on is using a technical preview of Windows from the Windows Insider program. I'm referring to [link](http://www.networkworld.com/article/3143196/windows/microsoft-is-replacing-the-cmd-prompt-with-powershell.html) So CMD is around still but I believe under the hood from my java program that builds the command `String[]` PowerShell is being used to execute it. And my results from copy-pasting the command into CMD and PowerShell support that.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. To elaborate on PowerShell 'replacing' CMD. I was thinking that with the latest preview builds of windows the process created by java code `Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] cmdArray, String[] envp, File dir);` was run in PowerShell not Command Prompt now. Although my initial attempts seemed to support that theory, the error was actually in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

Running `javac` in CMD shouldn't be required. Just put quotes around arguments that (may) contain whitespace or special characters. I'd also recommend using the [call operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) (`&`). It's optional in this case, but required if you put the executable in quotes (e.g. because the executable or path contains spaces or you want to put it in a variable).

```
& javac -cp "PATH1;PATH2" -d "DESTINATION_PATH" "SOURCE_PATH"
```

You could also use [splatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for providing the arguments:

```
$javac  = "$env:JAVA_HOME\bin\javac.exe"
$params = '-cp', "PATH1;PATH2",
          '-d', "DESTINATION_PATH",
          "SOURCE_PATH"

& $javac @params
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment regarding putting `PATH1;PATH2` in double quotes. That solved the problem in part. I can call `javac` from CMD but I don't think I have set up properly for PowerShell to work with just `javac`. I'm pretty sure your splatting solution would do the trick though.

Comment: The only thing you should need for a basic setup are the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` (pointing to the folder where your JDK is installed) and the path to `javac.exe` (usually `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`) in your `PATH` environment variable. Both environment variables affect CMD and PowerShell, i.e. if you have your setup working in CMD it should also be working in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

javac -classpath "path1:path2:." main.java does the trick in powershell. the cmd doesn't need the doble quotes however while using powershell we need to put the quotes and it works smoothly.

Comment: Although this answer is on the right track, the ':' will not work.  It needs to be a semicolon ';'.